# Counter doesn't increment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, count, increment

Relatively new to coding, so there might be a clear mistake in the code. What I am trying to do is have a counter that increases by one each time a new product is added to the basket.

When the program is run, its default value is 0, when the you click on the first product to add to the basket, it increases to 1, however, if you add any more products it sticks at 1 instead of increasing each time.

I have included the code below - is there an obvious mistake I am over looking being a novice (I'll be the first to attempt that ha!). No error message is thrown at any point.

```
protected void BtnAddToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ProductID = Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString();
        string ProductStock = "1";

        DataListItem currentItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;
        Label lblAvailableStock = currentItem.FindControl("lblAvailableStock") as Label;

        if (Session["MyBasket"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["My Basket"];
            var checkProduct = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID);
            if (checkProduct.Count() == 0)
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
                DataTable dtProduct = GetData(query);

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
                dr["ProductName"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductName"]);
                dr["ProductDescription"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductDescription"]);
                dr["ProductPrice"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPrice"]);
                dr["ProductStock"] = ProductStock;
                dr["ProductImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductImageUrl"]);
                dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                Session["MyBasket"] = dt;
                btnShoppingBasket.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID =" + ProductID + "";
            DataTable dtProduct = GetData(query);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductDescription", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductPrice", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductStock", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductImageUrl", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("AvailableStock", typeof(string));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
            dr["ProductName"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductName"]);
            dr["ProductDescription"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductDescription"]);
            dr["ProductPrice"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPrice"]);
            dr["ProductStock"] = ProductStock;
            dr["ProductImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductImageUrl"]);
            dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            Session["My Basket"] = dt;
            btnShoppingBasket.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

[Counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/606UD.png)

Comment: Is that what ProductStock is supposed to do?

Comment: ProductStock is the quantity that was added to the DB by the admin when adding the product.

Comment: So, does your current code attempt to have a counter? If so, what is the counter named?

Comment: It's the btnShoppingBasket which is a LinkButton - Image added to post

Comment: You should develop the habit of not using select *. You should only select the columns you actually need. You should also read about and utilize parameterized queries instead of building up a string and executing it.

Comment: For the actual issue at hand it can't ever be more than 1. You create a new DataTable and then add 1 row to it when there is not an existing cart. When there is an existing cart you get the count of rows where the ProductID is the one being added to the cart. Unless you have multiple rows in your Product table for the same ProductID it will never be more than 1. To be honest, this seems to be missing something. You should probably have a table with cart items which you seem to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see it appears that you create new basket every time an item is added into the basket. The little mistake is that you use different names of saved basket entry in session:

```
if (Session["MyBasket"] != null)
```

This will be false first time so it goes into else block.

```
Session["My Basket"] = dt;
```

Here you store new DataTable with different key. So the next time the if statement will still be false. So just make sure that the name is consistent. `"MyBasket" != "My Basket"`

Comment: Goodness me that is embarrassing- what a silly mistake! So easy to overlook when you have been staring at a piece of code for so long!! Thanks very much for the second set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed where "MyBasket" was "My Basket"; reduced code duplication. The misspelling is a compelling reason to use constants instead of string literals.

```
protected void BtnAddToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ProductID = Convert.ToInt16((((Button)sender).CommandArgument)).ToString();
    string ProductStock = "1";

    DataListItem currentItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;
    Label lblAvailableStock = currentItem.FindControl("lblAvailableStock") as Label;

    if (Session["MyBasket"] == null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductDescription", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductPrice", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductStock", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductImageUrl", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("AvailableStock", typeof(string));
    }

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["MyBasket"];
    var checkProduct = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("ProductID") == ProductID);
    if (checkProduct.Count() == 0)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID = " + ProductID + "";
        DataTable dtProduct = GetData(query);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ProductID"] = ProductID;
        dr["ProductName"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductName"]);
        dr["ProductDescription"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductDescription"]);
        dr["ProductPrice"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductPrice"]);
        dr["ProductStock"] = ProductStock;
        dr["ProductImageUrl"] = Convert.ToString(dtProduct.Rows[0]["ProductImageUrl"]);
        dr["AvailableStock"] = lblAvailableStock;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["MyBasket"] = dt;
        btnShoppingBasket.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```